# GCP logging driver: failed to initialise

Tags: docker

I am failing to understand where the issue might be. That's what I run and what I get as the error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/user/dolog/log-writer.json
docker -D run --log-driver=gcplogs \
--log-opt labels=location \
--log-opt gcp-project=scg-log-test \
--log-opt env=TEST \
--log-opt env=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS \
--log-opt gcp-log-cmd=true \
--env "TEST=false" \
--env "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/user/dolog/log-writer.json" \
--label location=west \
--name PYTEST \
--rm \
pytest

DEBU[0001] Corrupted prefix: []
DEBU[0001] [hijack] End of stdout
/usr/bin/docker-latest: Error response from daemon: Failed to initialize logging driver: google.DefaultTokenSource: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information..
```

Docker version:

```
Server Version: 1.12.1
```

Server version:

```
3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variable needs to be defined for the docker service, not the "docker run".

It is done in /etc/sysconfig/docker file.