# Enable gcplogging on GCE with docker

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

When starting the GCE,  it automatically pulls and runs the docker image. I can't pass an argument to the docker run command (as far as I know), so I can't pass the argument `--log-driver="gcplogs"`. The 2nd option docker specifies is adjusting the daemon.json file. However, on GCE these changes are not persisted, hence on a reboot this file is the default file.

Am I looking over something? How can I set the log-driver from docker on a google compute engine?

[Edit] I was able to get it working by choosing a container specialized OS, instead of a normal one. Then at the bottom in the management page you can set the following meta-data:

`google-logging-enabled: true`

https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/logging#Console

Comment: Can you share some reproducible steps? Or Any error messages you encounter?

Comment: There's not really an error going on. I just didn't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check below docs and other same issues that already answered by the community.

Docs:
[Using the Google Cloud Logging driver for Docker](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver?hl=en) 
**Cloud Logging driver for a single container**

1. After the instance is created, click the SSH button to open a terminal connected to the machine.
2. To use the Google Cloud logging driver for Docker, specify the `--log-driver=gcplogs` command-line argument to the docker run command.

Run the following command to start an NGINX container which writes logs to Cloud Logging:

```
docker run -d \
    --name mysite \
    --log-driver=gcplogs \
    -p 80:80 \
    nginx
```

**Google Cloud Logging driver with Docker Compose** 
When using Docker Compose, specify a logging driver for each service in the `docker-compose.yml` configuration file. For example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    logging:
      driver: gcplogs
    ...
  database:
    logging:
      driver: gcplogs
    ...
```

[Google Cloud Logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/)

Stackoverflow 
[GCP logging driver: failed to initialise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581036/gcp-logging-driver-failed-to-initialise) 
[The Google Cloud Logging driver for Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983216/the-google-cloud-logging-driver-for-docker)

Comment: Thanks :) Unfortunately I already saw these and do not help